# Better ways of catching Request and Response Headers?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, model-view-controller

Im currently working in MVC and I have what I see as crude ways of catching response and request headers on my pages.

First is Response headers which I currently handle on the page

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var name = "Comp"; 
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open('GET', document.location, false);
    req.send(null);
    var myHeader = req.getResponseHeader(name);
    alert(myHeader);
});
```

it makes a new request when the document is ready which could ruin the header if it isn't pretty static (wouldn't work if the header were to change between the sessions) but it currently workes.

I do catch the Request header inside of the controller

```
public new ActionResult Profile()
    {
        var head = Request.Headers.GetValues("Comp");
        try
        {
            if (head != null)
            {
                string id = head.First();
                ViewBag.message = head.First(); //controll
                return View();
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            ViewBag.message = "Header method Failed";
        }
        return View();
    }
```

Now I wonder if there are better ways of doing this. Someone enlighten me.

Comment: There's no way to get the headers of the current page request in JS, as it executes too late in the pipeline to catch them. Then only way to read them is to do what you currently are; make another request to the same page via AJAX and read them from the response. Note that this is not at all scalable though, as you're effectively doubling the load on the server. I'd ask why you feel the need to read the headers on the client side when you can access them in your C# MVC logic and inject them in to the page.

Comment: Yes, this sounds like an [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why send data via headers in the first place?